# Get text from first cell of row through button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table whose data is loaded dynamically, and I am also adding buttons to each row which I now want to have functionality. For this I need to get the text from the first cell on the row that is clicked.

I have tried several different code snippets but most return absolutely nothing.

[image: https://gyazo.com/6fdcc9d93d2479e0067aea7bde6b3d95]

This illustrates what I need to achieve, this when "Add comment" is clicked. The cell does not have any ID or specific class.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not rely on external resources that can vanish, making the question useless to others in the future.

Comment: Zugo please add sample HTML etc. thanks

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: I understand, but what code is necessary here? I have tried every alternative that's on SO and jquery isn't giving me any errors, so I guess the only thing I can show is my html, is so I will update the OP with my html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think this code might get you on the right track.

All I did was add an event listener to your `table` and implemented some event delegation (meaning event will bubble up the DOM tree and will be handled by a parent element - this reduces the number of event listeners needed in our code).

Generally, I wouldn't recommend to writing code like this. You should use real data structures to store and manipulate your data instead of having to hack away at a bunch of DOM elements and nodes. You might also want to consider looking to [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to suit your needs.

```js
//A click event handler function
const getFileId = e => {
  if (e.target.type === 'button') {
    const td = e.target.parentElement;
    const tr = td.parentElement;
    const [s] = tr.children;
    return s.innerText
  }
  return null;
};

//A reference to our table element
const tableEl = document.querySelector('#tableEl');

//Set the click event handler function to fire whenever the table is clicked
tableEl.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const fileId = getFileId(e);
  if (fileId) {
    console.log(`Add comment to ${fileId}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="tableEl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>File ID</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>108</td>
    <td>FileA.txt</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Comment" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>109</td>
    <td>FileB.txt</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Comment" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>FileC.txt</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Comment" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>FileD.txt</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add Comment" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```